# Atualizar Activity anterior ao finalizar Activity atual

Tags: android

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um projeto Android e estou com um problema vou tentar explicar de forma clara:

Possuo duas Activitys A e B, minha Activity A chama a B e permanece na pilha, após encerrar as ações na B essa finaliza e retorna para a A (retorna pois a A estava na pilha). Esta Activity B altera dados no servidor que mudam a exibição na A, por isso preciso que ao finalizar a B, a A atualize para exibir tais mudanças.
Existe alguma forma de fazer esta atualização ou recarregar a Activity A assim que a B for finalizada?

Detalhe: Antes da Activity A existem outras na pilha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul, acho que o modo mais simples e elegante para o seu caso é usar o próprio ciclo de vida da Activity para isso. Quando a Activity B for finalizada, a Activity A, que estava em 'stop' terá seu ciclo de vida percorrido afim de fazê-la sofrer 'restart'. Os métodos principais  chamados serão `onRestart()` -> `onStart()` -> `onResume()`. Perceba que o método onResume() é chamado na criação da Activity e no 'restart' dela!

Você pode colocar toda a comunicação com o web service no método `onResume()`, para que assim quando a Activity for criada o carregamento de dados aconteça e quando a activity for 'restartada' também aconteça. Sempre você terá os dados atualizados. É nesse sentido que recomendo sempre deixar o carregamento de dados no `onResume()` para que a tela sempre esteja atualizada.

Comment: Tássio, utilizei o método onRestart na Activity A e funcionou perfeitamente, ao retornar ele chama o método que interage com o web service e dessa forma carrega os dados atualizados. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Ótimo,  Paul! onRestart também soluciona o seu problema! Foi um prazer ajudá-lo!

Answer (score 2):

Olá, você pode chamar a Activity B, usando o StartActivityForResult

Activity A

```
private static final IDENTIFICADOR_B = 1;

Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(IDENTIFICADOR_B  1);
```

Sobreescreva na activity A o método onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == IDENTIFICADOR_B ) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String resposta = data.getStringExtra("tag"); //resposta = "atualizar"
           //Atualizar mais coisas aqui
        }
    }
}
```

Em sua Activity B, finalize assim:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("tag","atualizar");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Espero ter ajudado...

Comment: Uma alternativa é utilizar o método `onStart()` ou `onResume()` que será chamado ao retornar à *Activity* **A**, depois de **B** finalizar.